# Can I use Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I'm thinking to reinstall Ubuntu on my machine and would love to have Unity back.

I can't get used to Gnome.

What is the best way to get Unity back on the recent releases of Ubuntu?

Or is there an alternative to Unity?

The feature I miss the most is the <kbd>Alt</kbd> search for a menu item.

Comment: @pomsky Is Unity still maintained?

Comment: @IonicăBizău From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)): *On 5 April 2017 Mark Shuttleworth announced that Canonical's work on Unity would end and that Ubuntu would employ the GNOME 3 desktop instead. However, the UBports team forked the Unity 8 repository and continued the development. Currently, the Unity 8 project is maintained and developed by UBports.*

Comment: `alt` + `F2`  [usually] opens a prompt that will allow you to search or run commands and programs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Going back to Unity**

If you have been using Unity or GNOME in the past, you may not like the new customized GNOME desktop in Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu has customized GNOME so that it resembles Unity but at the end of the day, it is neither completely Unity nor completely GNOME.

Open up a terminal window. Then run the following two commands to install **Unity 7 desktop** from the default software repository.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

This will install a lot of packages. Once the installation is complete, restart your Ubuntu 18.04 computer.

You can also install **Unity Tweaks** via the Software Center or you can use the command below to install it:

```
$ sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

**How to Install Unity Desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?**

1. Open up a terminal window.
   Then run the following two commands to install Unity 7 desktop from the default software repository.

   ```
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
   ```

   This will install a lot of packages. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue.
2. During the installation, you will be asked to choose a display manager. You can choose **lightdm** display manager, which will give you the Unity Login screen. **gdm3** is the default display manager for GNOME desktop.

   [image]

   **Note:**

   a) Use <kbd>↑</kbd>or<kbd>↓</kbd> to position the cursor on your choice of default desktop manager
   b) Hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to mark your selection (Don't ignore this step).
   c) Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to `OK` button and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
3. Once the installation is complete, restart your Ubuntu 18.04 computer.

   ```
   $ sudo shutdown -r now
   ```
4. Now you are greeted by Unity login screen. What a warm feeling to have it back!

   Double-click **Ubuntu symbol** in LightDM or **gear** symbol in GDM to display options for desktop environments.

   [image]

   The default desktop environment is now `Unity`. You can click the `Ubuntu` icon to choose another desktop environment if you want to.

   [image]
5. If you upgraded from `Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04` and the login screen was replaced with the one from GNOME desktop, you can restore Unity login screen by running the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
   ```

   And here’s the good old Unity desktop.

   [image]
6. Checking Unity Version

   You can use the `screenfetch` tool to check Unity desktop version.

   ```
   $ sudo apt install screenfetch
   ```

   [image]

   Now, give the following useful command to display not only version info, but also other system details:

   ```
   $ screenfetch
   ```

   [image]

   As you can see, we have installed Unity 7.5.0.

   You can also acquire `Unity version` by running the following command.

   ```
   $ unity --version
   ```

   [image]

   Since we installed Unity, why not install the Unity tweak tool?

   ```
   $ sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
   ```
7. How to Remove GNOME Desktop from Ubuntu 18.04?

   If you don’t want to keep `GNOME` on the list of available desktop environments, uninstall it with the following command.

   ```
   $ sudo apt remove gnome-shell
   ```

   If you now restart Ubuntu 18.04 OS, there will be no `GNOME desktop` in the login screen options.

Comment: Please indeed add a reason why this would not advisable, or remove the "not recommended" from the title. In addition, your answer only covers returning to Unity (which it should, because that is the question. So remove the "vanilla GNOME" from your title. Finally, you may want to add how to log in to the Unity desktop. Only rebooting won't cut it.

Comment: I see your point @vanadium. Strictly no drifting away from question! I am removing the phrase "Vanilla Gnome" from my title. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Marmayogi I followed your answer and everything worked fine. I have Unity again! Will I get the updates from the new maintainer or do I have to add a specific repository for that?

Comment: @Ionică Bizău, I must tell you that the Unity packages are not in the main repository anymore. Now, these are served from the [Universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-unity-desktop) and packages in the Universe repository are community maintained. Ubuntu developers don’t work directly on these packages any more. In other words, the Unity you are going to use in Ubuntu 18.04 is community maintained. Is it really a bad thing? Not really. You can use them as long as the project is alive and not abandoned completely.